# Enum class not found when trying to use it in settings.php

Tags: configuration, 10

I defined an enum in a custom module:

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Enum;

enum BuildType: string {
  case Apple = 'apple_build';
  case Orange = 'orange_build';
}
```

And I want to use it in settings.php to change the config directory of the site:

**settings.php**:

```
$build_type = BuildType::from(getenv('build_type'));

$settings['config_sync_directory'] = dirname(DRUPAL_ROOT) . '/config/base_' . $build_type->value;

$settings['custom_translations_directory'] = dirname(DRUPAL_ROOT) . '/translations/' . $build_type->value;
```

However, when I do this, I get a namespace error:

`Error: Class "Drupal\my_module\Enum\BuildType" not found in /var/www/html/web/sites/default/settings.custom.php on line 14 #0 /var/www/html/web/sites/default/settings.php(32): include()`

How can I correctly namespace my enum for use in settings.php?

Comment: Is your module enabled? Also please post the "use" statement you included.

Comment: Since the error is about `Drupal\my_module\Enum\BuildType`, it must be `use Drupal\my_module\Enum\BuildType;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *settings.php* file is loaded from [`DrupalKernel::initializeSettings()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DrupalKernel.php/function/DrupalKernel%3A%3AinitializeSettings/9), which is called from [`DrupalKernel::handle()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DrupalKernel.php/function/DrupalKernel%3A%3Ahandle/9) before [`DrupalKernel::boot()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DrupalKernel.php/function/DrupalKernel%3A%3Aboot/9).

See the code in [`Settings::initialize()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Site%21Settings.php/function/Settings%3A%3Ainitialize/9), called by `DrupalKernel::initializeSettings()`.

```php
if (is_readable($app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.php')) {
  require $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.php';
}
```

This means that when the code in *settings.php* is executed, the dependency injection container hasn't yet initialized, the services aren't yet available, and modules are not loaded. Classes/interfaces/traits defined from contributed/custom modules are not yet available either.

Since the *settings.php* file does not have access to classes/interfaces a module defines, it should load the file containing the class/interface definition directly or define the class/interface itself. Since the *settings.php* file is loaded with `require`, the code to load the class file or declaring the class should be wrapped in an `if` statement.

```php
if (!class_exists('BuildType')) {
  // Load the class file or declare the class.
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I tried defining the enum inside a file included by `settings.php`, I get an error when I run a command such as `drush site-install minimal`: `Cannot declare enum BuildType, because the name is already in use in /var/www/html/web/sites/default/settings.my_module.php`. Simply adding an enum definition to `settings.php` triggers this error.

Comment: When you get that error, was the `enum` defined in a single place?

Comment: Anyway, since the *settings.php* is loaded with `require`, the class declaration should be put between `if (!class_exists('BuildType') {` and `}`, in the *settings.php* file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code based on apaderno's answer:

**settings.php**:

```
if (!class_exists('BuildType') {
  enum BuildType: string {
    case Apple = 'apple_build';
    case Orange = 'orange_build';
  }
}

$build_type = BuildType::from(getenv('build_type'));

$settings['config_sync_directory'] = dirname(DRUPAL_ROOT) . '/config/base_' . $build_type->value;

$settings['custom_translations_directory'] = dirname(DRUPAL_ROOT) . '/translations/' . $build_type->value;
```